# Firefox for Android: How to specify timezone ≠ UTC with `privacy.resistFingerprinting=true`?

Tags: privacy, firefox-for-android, time-zones

I use Firefox for Android ([Mull](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/us.spotco.fennec_dos)). I have "resist fingerprinting" (`privacy.resistFingerprinting` in about:config) enabled. That results in Firefox being forced to report its time in UTC to websites. Some timetable query sites show me the results in the client's time, so in UTC, which is really confusing.

On Firefox for Android, I also don't find an extension to change my browser's timezone, like "[Change Timezone (Time Shift) – Get this Extension for  Firefox (en-US)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/change-timezone-time-shift/)" that is available for "Desktop"-Firefox.

How can I set in Firefox for Android my browser's timezone to my operating system's or a self-chosen value while still having `privacy.resistFingerprinting` enabled?